# Cannot install R Shiny Server on WSL Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am unable to install Shiny server on my WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
I get the error after I run this line:
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.9.923-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.9.923-amd64.deb

This is the error I keep getting:

/var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst: 97: /var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst: initctl: not found
/var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst: 99: /var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst: initctl: not found

Kindly help.

Tried changing the initctl in /var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst to systemctl but it did not help

I followed the instructions on the R shiny server page

Comment: [You may need to install upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746615/initctl-reload-configuration-command-not-found).

Comment: @neilfws I tried that same link. I did the same after that and it still gave me that error. Can you guide me?

Comment: @Keith, any luck with this? There doesn't seem to be any info on whether or not it's even possible to run shiny server on WSL/Ubuntu. I suspect it's related to the fact that WSL doesn't support initctl. Upstart seems to be another service manager, but it's not clear if I can use it on the latest Ubuntu. Perhaps there's a way to just run shiny without making it a service?

Comment: I figured it out. It is possible to install shiny server on WSL. You will need to build it from source. Follow the steps on here. https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source

Answer (score 1):

This is working as of July,2020.  No need to build from source.

```
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.14.948-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.14.948-amd64.deb
```